# Ways to keep up with an academic talk (especially in mathematics)

Tags: mathematics, presentation

I am a maths masters student, and I am getting very frustrated with how little I get out of academic talks. I would love some advice on how to change this.

I feel like there are a few problems:

1. Not understanding the material at the pace that it is presented. This could include notation, definitions, something conceptual, missing an 'obvious' way of viewing the problem due that makes certain things obvious etc
2. Attention drifting for a brief period of time and missing a small remark- or something more important- that clarifies what we are doing in the proof and why.
3. Not writing down/committing to memory the right things. For instance, the form of some function or its general asymptotic behaviour.

I appreciate that for 1. and 3. the best solution is probably just gaining more experience in the research area that is being presented. That way, I will have a better feel for what parameters/quantities are important to keep track of as well. However I still feel like I generally do a worse job than most at following talks...

I am currently participating in a reading group in my area of interest; the audience is a mixture of masters students like me, with very similar backgrounds, and PhD students. In every talk/presentation so far, I have gotten quite lost by about mid-way through, so find myself unable to come up with sensible questions to ask. And yet, most of the other masters students usually have insightful questions that demonstrate they understood the lecture; they are able to discuss the material, linking it to things presented in earlier talks as well. I just sit there feeling like a lemon.

I was wondering if I have a short-term memory impairment... My brain seems to be like a sieve unless I have a good conceptual understanding of something. But there is too much to write down to keep track of the things that are new!

Hopefully people could share their approaches to getting something out of academic talks in mathematics. For example:

1. How much do you write down? What do you write? (definitions, theorems, key elements of a proof?) In how much detail?
2. Any specific tips for maintaining attention during the talk, or trying to get back on track after missing something and feeling a little lost.
3. Do you make summary or revision tool after a talk? This would probably be especially good for the reading group; though it is difficult to do when I feel like I didn't understand the talk- what would I write down?

Note: I have heard of a method of writing 3 important things to remember, but I still find it confusing as to what those three things should be. IF someone could give a concrete example from a talk they themselves attended, that would be great.

Comment: One approach is to think of ways the speaker could make the talk more understandable, more interesting, or more memorable.